# Is there a more elegant way to handle local storage API usage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am developing a browser extension, that uses local storage to store URLs.

the local storage is used in background script and in script for the popup and extension options.

Whenever a function needs these sites, it basically makes an API call to retrieve them.
But I was wondering, if there is a better way to get these data and not call the API from multiple functions all the time. (for example store it in a file or a variable)

for now, i retrieve data like this:

```
let whiteList = browser.storage.local.get("whiteList");
  whiteList.then((res) => {
    // check if there are any blacklisted sites
    if (!res.whiteList || res.whiteList.left < 1) {
      whiteListedSites = [];
      // parse blackListed sites to object
    } else {
      whiteListedSites = JSON.parse(res.whiteList);
    }
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: 1) What's wrong with reading storage all the time? This way you'll always have current data even if it's changed in another tab by your extension. 2) No need for JSON.parse and JSON.stringify - storage supports arrays and objects.

Comment: Since  this is my first extension, I was just curious if my approach was correct. Also thanks for the advice, really appreciate it. My question was rather related to repeating the same code in several functions, so I think the best solution will be creating a function for this.

Comment: See how to use async/await syntax, then you can simply do this: whiteListedSites = await browser.storage.local.get({whiteList: []});

Comment: With chrome.storage API you don't need async/await. It is preferable to use it

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to use the storage API and call it every time you need it. The solution with the file is by far the worst. Reading from a file is a very slow operation and it is not recommended. On the other hand, if you store the list in a variable this variable will be accessible only from the script that declares it. The storage API is not slow so you can call it every time without any performance issue. In addition if you call the API every time you need the list, you will be sure that you will have always updated data. I have also created a Chrome Extension and I call the API whenever I need to read the data.

In addition it is better in Chrome extensions to use the chrome.storage API that is part of the Chrome Extension API and it has many advantages over the localStorageAPI. It is faster, asynchronous, you can access it from content scripts and not only from background script and much more (see here for details (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#overview))

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure if I explained myself correctly. For now, I use the storage like this, but there are multiple functions that use the same code again and again. So I was wondering if I should create a function, that would get the data from storage and return them using callback. and then call this function instead to remove code duplicates. Hope you understand me :)

Comment: "a function, that would get the data from storage and return them using callback. and then call this function instead to remove code duplicates" What do you mean? Please be more exact to can answer your question. @Koleslav